# Java bytecode manipulation?

Tags: java, class, assembly, hex, bytecode

So, I'm writing an AV, and I'm developing hooks for a sandbox thing, and I have a problem:
I can't edit the java.lang.* files, nor can I overwrite them with a classloader.
Whenever I try to edit the bytes of a class file, no good happens. Say, I have a copy of the source code from Runtime(with reflection for the restricted bits), works 100% the same as the one in java.lang, I can't modify the bytes to change all references from the lang one to my custom one. Look at this, I compile this class, which just opens notepad.exe:

```
Êþº¾...3.(......Start......java/lang/Object...<init>...()V...Code.............LineNumberTable...LocalVariableTable...this...LStart;...main...([Ljava/lang/String;)V...........java/lang/Runtime........getRuntime...()Ljava/lang/Runtime;......notepad.exe.............exec..'(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;...........java/io/IOException.. .....printStackTrace...args...[Ljava/lang/String;...e...Ljava/io/IOException;...StackMapTable...SourceFile...Start.java.!......................./........*·..±...............................................g........¸....¶..W§..L+¶..±.................................................!.".......#.$...%......L.......&.....'
```

I got the text dump from HxD.

Then I replace all occurrences of java/lang/Runtime with JavaProphet/JoustJAV/sandbox/Runtime and I get this:

```
Êþº¾...3.(......Start......java/lang/Object...<init>...()V...Code.............LineNumberTable...LocalVariableTable...this...LStart;...main...([Ljava/lang/String;)V...........JavaProphet/JoustJAV/sandbox/Runtime........getRuntime...()LJavaProphet/JoustJAV/sandbox/Runtime;......notepad.exe.............exec..'(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;...........java/io/IOException.. .....printStackTrace...args...[Ljava/lang/String;...e...Ljava/io/IOException;...StackMapTable...SourceFile...Start.java.!......................./........*·..±...............................................g........¸....¶..W§..L+¶..±.................................................!.".......#.$...%......L.......&.....'
```

Now, if I run the first file, notepad opens, if I open the second file, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 74 in class file Start
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at JavaProphet.JoustJAV.SandboxCL.findClass(SandboxCL.java:152)
at JavaProphet.JoustJAV.SandboxCL.loadClass(SandboxCL.java:97)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at JavaProphet.JoustJAV.FileScanner.sandboxFile(FileScanner.java:335)
at JavaProphet.JoustJAV.FileScanner.sandboxFile(FileScanner.java:348)
at JavaProphet.JoustJAV.MainWindow$4.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:120)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Now, I assume that those dots are integers or some sort of indexing for the data in the class file, but what do I need to change to get this class file to work? I've looked into ASM, but I didn't see a class replacement mechanism. Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I just turned each byte of hex data into deciaml, and compared it with relative lengths, blah blah blah, so I changed the following:

```
Êþº¾...3.(......Start......java/lang/Object...<init>...()V...Code.............LineNumberTable...LocalVariableTable...this...LStart;...main...([Ljava/lang/String;)V..........$JavaProphet/JoustJAV/sandbox/Runtime........getRuntime..(()LJavaProphet/JoustJAV/sandbox/Runtime;......notepad.exe.............exec..'(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;...........java/io/IOException.. .....printStackTrace...args...[Ljava/lang/String;...e...Ljava/io/IOException;...StackMapTable...SourceFile...Start.java.!......................./........*·..±...............................................g........¸....¶..W§..L+¶..±.................................................!.".......#.$...%......L.......&.....'
```

If you look closely, you can see the beginning symbols are different for my custom class, so now my sandbox can safely run file that use runtime(I'm working on processbuilder) to retrieve virus-sensitive running things.

Comment: Note that this is still highly vulnerable. Java sandboxing is very hard to get right (even Oracle hasn't quite managed it). If you lack even basic knowledge about bytecode like this, you may as well forget it. Anyway, you should be running the entire JVM inside of a sandbox for extra security.